# Spring security overriding access xml config

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it possible to override the access roles to a certain page? I have a site that uses AD log in so all the users will have access to most of the page but a few page would have a access for admin users. Can I do something like this?

`<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
 <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />`

instead of giving roles to each mapping separately?

Comment: Yes, that possible but the order of `<intercept-url pattern..` matters. Your above config will allow every authenticated User to access every URL. Reverse the order, then `/admin/**` will be restricted to `ADMIN` while everything else will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks. I tried switching too but nothing was working. It turns out, SVN restored my spring-security.xml to my original directory after I moved it to a different directory, and I was changing the wrong file.

Comment: So is it working now?